# xCode 6: No Development Profile in drop down in Build Settings

Tags: xcode, ios8, xcode6, code-signing, build-settings

I've tried to debug a project on my iPhone 5 today and received errors everytime I was launching it:

> - process launch failed: timed out waiting for app to launch
> - process launch failed: failed to get the task for process *multiple numbers*

I found out that these kind of errors are indicating that my "Code Signing IDs" aren't set correctly. But when I want to change the IDs in the drop down menu, there are just the "Distribution Profile" and the "Automatic" setting but no "Development Profile".

I've tried to download the certificate from the DeveloperCenter, replace it, save it in the Keychain again, etc. but nothing helps. It seems that I can't do anything to let the Development Profile appear in the drop down.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

After deselecting and reselecting the Team-ID in the "General" setting, xCode synchronised and it appears a "iPhone Developer" option for CodeSigningIdentity -> Debug, Release but not for the their drop down options "Any iOS SDK". Unfortunately it doesn't work with the changes. I am missing the usual "*iPhone Developer: MY_NAME (MY_ID)*" option.

Answer (score 0):

Did you select the appropriate Team on your project's General page? Check out Xcode's Preferences pane as well.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I checked it and xCode synchronised. Just for CodeSigningIdentity->Debug and -> Release (not for Any iOS SDK) the "iPhone Developer" option appears but not with my name after it as usual ("iPhone Developer: My Name (ID)"). Unfortunately there was no change in the functionality, so there are always the errors.